# Getting elements from multiple html pages into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, dom-manipulation

I have two html pages called home.html and about.html.
And I also have a js file called main.js which is linked with both of the html pages.I have a div with a class of "home" in home.html and another div with a class of "about" in about.html. Class "home" has a text and class "about" has a text too.Now I slected them in my main.js file like this,

```
const home = document.querySelector('.home')
const about = document.querySelector('.about')
```

And manipulated them like this,

```
home.style.color = 'red'
about.style.color = 'green'
```

But the problem is only the variable  'home' is changing its color not the variable
'about'

I think there is maybe a particular way to select elements from multiple pages.
But if there is pls let me know bcz the variable 'about' is not getting manipulated with anything.

```js
const home = document.querySelector('.home')
const about = document.querySelector('.about')

// Manipulated them like this
home.style.color = 'red'
about.style.color = 'green'
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>ES8 Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" /> </head>

<body>
  <div class="home"> HOME </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How exactly have you loaded two files into a single document?

Comment: My guess is that there's some error in your code that we cannot deduce from the short snippets of code in your question.

Comment: Now, where is `about.html`?

Comment: Also post the JS file in the snippet

Comment: And why use JS to do CSS' work?

Comment: Working css in js is just to show the error

Comment: And about file here <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="about">
   ABOUT
 </div>
 <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>

</html>

Comment: Ah, now I understood the issue. You've the same script on both of the pages. The script doesn't work on about.html, because there's no `.home` element, and the attempt to set `null.style.color` triggers an error. When an error occurs, the execution of the script is stopped, that's why the other style setting will never work. You've to check the existence of the elements before trying to access their properties, like `if(home) {home.style.color = ...;}`. Or optionally change the class name of the `div`s to something more generic, so that both of the pages can use the same code (`class="intro"`)

Comment: Notice, that the script triggers an error also on home.html page, but after setting the style for `.home` element. You've to get familiar with the DevTools, hit F12 on your browser, and an entire new world will be opened to you.

Comment: Thanks to you all for responding on my question .

Comment: I think now I understand the issue and its time to work on that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than:

```
<div class="home"> HOME </div>
<div class="about"> ABOUT </div>
```

You can use a *custom data attribute* like `data-page`:

```
<div data-page="home"> HOME </div>
<div data-page="about"> ABOUT </div>
```

Then, if you want to do something more dynamic than straightforward CSS styling, you can script the following:

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector('[data-page]');

switch (myDiv.dataset.page) {

  case ('home') : [... DO SOMETHING... ] ; break;
  case ('about') : [... DO SOMETHING... ] ; break;
}
```

---

**N.B.** When using this setup, where you **do** only want to apply CSS styling, then *definitely* use CSS:

```
[data-page="home"] {
  color: red;
}

[data-page="about"] {
  color: green;
}
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Thank you sir,I will definitely try it